# What is meant by "effectively unlimited stream"

Tags: java, random, java-8, stream, java-stream

I was reading new enhancement in [java 8 Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class and there is this term **effectively unlimited stream** used repeatedly.

Consider [IntStream ints(int randomNumberOrigin,
                      int randomNumberBound)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-int-int-) :

> Returns an effectively unlimited stream of pseudorandom int values,
>   each conforming to the given origin (inclusive) and bound (exclusive).

Could someone please explain this term.

Comment: Why down-voted?? could you please care to explain?

Comment: [effectively](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/effectively) (definition 2), [unlimited](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unlimited) (also definition 2)

Comment: @user2357112 I asked this question in context of `java stream` not `Grammar`

Comment: @user2357112 Could you look at the answer, and see there is **A BIG DIFFERENCE** between `Unlimited in Grammar` and   `Unlimited in Java`

Comment: The question is *answerable* by looking the words up in the dictionary. Yeah, it's not unlimited, but it's *effectively* unlimited: "in effect : virtually".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means you can treat it as unlimited, but it might technically not be unlimited. For example, the [openjdk 8u40-b25 implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Random.java?av=f#724) returns a stream of `Long.MAX_VALUE` elements:

```
public IntStream ints(int randomNumberOrigin, int randomNumberBound) {
    if (randomNumberOrigin >= randomNumberBound)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(BadRange);
    return StreamSupport.intStream
            (new RandomIntsSpliterator
                     (this, 0L, Long.MAX_VALUE, randomNumberOrigin, randomNumberBound),
             false);
}
```

you see that it calls `new RandomIntsSpliterator (this, 0L, Long.MAX_VALUE, randomNumberOrigin, randomNumberBound)`.

The Javadoc of `RandomIntsSpliterator` says:

> Spliterator for int streams. We multiplex the four int versions into one class by treating a bound less than origin as unbounded, and also by **treating "infinite" as equivalent to Long.MAX_VALUE**. For splits, it uses the standard divide-by-two approach. The long and double versions of this class are identical except for types.

This means that "effectively unlimited stream" here is implemented as an actually finite stream with a lot of elements (`Long.MAX_VALUE` of them). For all practical purposes I guess it can be viewed as an unlimited stream, since the chance anyone will want to use this method to produce more than `Long.MAX_VALUE` random `int`s is probably very small.

If you look at a similar variant of `ints` that returns an `IntStream` of a requested size:

```
public IntStream ints(long streamSize, int randomNumberOrigin,
                      int randomNumberBound) {
    if (streamSize < 0L)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(BadSize);
    if (randomNumberOrigin >= randomNumberBound)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(BadRange);
    return StreamSupport.intStream
            (new RandomIntsSpliterator
                     (this, 0L, streamSize, randomNumberOrigin, randomNumberBound),
             false);
}
```

you see that calling

```
ints(min,max)
```

is equivalent to calling

```
ints(Long.MAX_VALUE,min,max)
```

at least in this implementation.

Comment: So `effectively unlimited stream` is equivalent  `stream of Long.MAX_VALUE`.  This actually is not unlimited.

Comment: The `Long.MAX_VALUE` number is an implementation detail, though. Future versions and other Java implementations are free to make it actually unlimited, or to pick a smaller or larger length, as long as the stream is still *effectively* unlimited.

Comment: @MehrajMalik: `java.util.Random` starts repeating after 2⁴⁸ values, so if your short-circuiting criteria wasn’t fulfilled after 281474976710656 elements, say after a few days, you can kill your application anyway, as otherwise, even if you manage to process one value in a nanosecond, you’ll need almost three hundred years to process `Long.MAX_VALUE` elements. But note that taking forever is not a guaranteed property of infinite streams, just a technical limitation, e.g. `random.ints().average()` could be calculated in finite time and there wouldn’t be anything wrong if the stream did.